# Symfony2: How to change the login_check route name to others and redirect

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

**Question 1**

How to change the login_check route to other naming route?

For example, the login form will post to www.example.com/auth instead of www.example.com/login_check. Then the auth will perform the checking like login_check.

**Question 2**

How to redirect user if they try to access /login when they already authenticated?

For example, when user try to access /login, if he/she already authenticated then will be redirected to /account instead of displaying the login form.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading the routes of a bundle inside the `src/Pk/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml` you can create an entry for the routes:

```
# src/Pk/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Home:index }
login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Auth:login}
login_check:
    pattern:  /auth
logout:
    pattern:  /logout
account:
    pattern:  /account
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Account:index}
```

and in your `security.yml` :

```
# app/config/security.yml
firewalls:
      main:
          pattern:    ^/
          form_login:
              check_path: login_check       # the name of your check route
              login_path: login             # the name of your login route
              default_target_path: account  # the name of your account route
              always_use_default_target_path: true
          logout:
              path:   logout
              target: /
          anonymous: ~
          remember_me:
              key:      "%secret%"
              lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
              path:     /
              domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

This should work using [Symfony 2.6 (Documentation)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#changing-the-default-page)

But it will allways redirect after login, if what you want is only when the client GET /login then you can use the controller:

```
# AppBundle:Auth
public function loginAction ()
{
    if($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('account'));
    }
    // logic of the loginpage
}
```

If you want more customization you can add a Login Event Listener for it. ([For example](https://gist.github.com/smottt/1075753))

If I didn't miss anything it should work.

If I get you wrong, please let me know, and I hope this will help you.

Comment: This should work using Symfony2.6. [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#changing-the-default-page)